# ReactJS onClick .next() element with same class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and I was wondering what is the correct way to target next element with same class in react?

```
<div className="portfolioGallery">
    <img className="portfolioImg activeImg" src="img/1.png"/>
    <img className="portfolioImg" src="img/2.png"/>
    <img className="portfolioImg" src="img/2.png"/>
  <div className="portfolioNext" onClick={this.nextImg.bind(this)}>
     Next image
  </div>
</div>
```

What would be the correct way that when I click the portfolioNext div I would be able to give the img2 class of activeImg and remove it from the previous element and so on in ReactJS?

Thank You!

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        default: "portfolioImg activeImg"
    };
}

nextImg() {
    this.setState({
        default: "portfolioImg"
    });
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your porfolioGallery component  should handle the active img in its state.

Comment: Yes, I understand this part. But I am not sure how to add the state to next element?

Comment: Could you add your react code ?

Comment: I added the constructor and the function. But not sure how to select the next element.

Comment: It looks like you're still thinking in terms of jQuery and using classes to identify things and modify them. I'd [read up a bit](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) on how to structure things in React.

Answer (score 3):

That's the kind of imperative technique that you'd generally find in jQuery code, but it doesn't map very well to React's slightly more declarative nature.

Rather than trying to find the next element with a class, use state to maintain a list of those elements alongside an index cursor.

```
// constructor
this.state = {
  images = ['img/1.png', 'img/2.png', 'img/3.png']
  cursor: 0
};
```

Then use these bits of data to render your view.

```
// render
const { images, cursor } = this.state;
return (
  <div>
    {images.map((src, index) => {
      const activeClass = (index === cursor) ? 'activeImg' : '';
      return <img className={`portfolioImg ${activeClass}`} />;
    }}
  </div>
);
```

To change the active image, use `setState` to change the `cursor` property.

```
// nextImg
const { cursor, images } = this.state;
const nextCursor = cursor % images.length;

this.setState({ cursor: nextCursor });
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest you think of it as siblings finding each other, but instead thing of it as the parent storing an index of the current children, and updating that instead.

`this.props` (or `this.state`) would have something like this (pseudocode)

```
this.props.images => ["img/1.png", "img/2.png", "img/2.png"];
```

Inside render:

```
<div className="portfolioGallery">
    {this.props.images.map((image, i ) => active === i ? (<img className="portfolioImg activeImg" src="image" key={i}/>) : (<img className="portfolioImg " src="image" key={i}/>))}
    <button className="portfolioNext" onClick={(e) => this.setState({active: this.state.active + 1}).bind(this)}>Next image</button>
</div>
```

Of course, accounting for when `active >= images.length`, but you get the idea